# Openui5 Local Development Issue(the Mockserver don't work on local environment)

Tags: localhost, sapui5

Now I'm learning UI5(Openui5/Sapui5). I'm first with UI5.

Now I've been reading and implementing below tutorials on my local
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic

Very good document, so everything was working well.

But Now I met one issue in below
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.m.tutorial.worklist/sample/sap.m.tutorial.worklist.03

I downloaded the source code from that page and was trying to on my local.

But it didn't work (other source code downloaded was working well)

-In Dialog Error
Sorry, a technical error occurred! Please try again later.

```
{
    "requestUri": "/northwind/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata?sap-language=EN",
    "statusCode": 404,
    "statusText": "Not Found",
    "headers": [],
    "body": "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n
    Cannot GET /northwind/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata
    \n\n\n"
}
```

-In console:
datajs.js:2592 GET http://localhost:8080/northwind/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata?sap-language=EN 404 (Not Found)

-Manifest Setting(Didn't make any change, below is in default, manifest.json)

```
"dataSources": {
    "mainService": {
        "uri": "/northwind/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/",
        "type": "OData",
        "settings": {
            "odataVersion": "2.0",
            "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml"
        }
    }
}
```

I've realized this problem is related to Local Mock Server. So i've researched via googling, but I've failed to find a good solution for about 3-4 hours.

How can I make this sample run correctly on my local dev env?
If anyone has a good solution, please guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: We don't know your setup but do you have a proxy to the northwind service?

Answer (score 0):

```
"dataSources": {
    "mainService": {
        "uri": "/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/",
        "type": "OData",
        "settings": {
            "odataVersion": "2.0",
            "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml"
        }
    }
}
```

Try this.